Is there any built-in parameter in powerBI Dashboard that means the same as &UserID in report builf
I have an access right table on Report Builder, which looks like this:
CustomerID SalesID      WindowsID
121        A
122        A
123        A
221        B
222        B
121        AA (A s manager)
122        AA (A s manager)
123        AA (A s manager)
In report builder, i can simply left join the access table with data table, stating WindowsID=&UserId （built in parameter in report builder), then every one can view their own customers.
Now I want to move this report to PowerBI Dashboard, instead of setting up rls again, is there a simple way that i can simply copy and use the same sql query to control access right? But in the "advanced option" in import data, “&UserId” parameter is not working...
PowerBI access control

Please post tables using markdown.
